# Laravel : how to query the result of query scope

Tags: mysql, laravel, collections

I have my query scope, it returns hundreds of records. I need to query this collection, with different filters, in the controller.

How I can do this? Is it possible?

Query scope:

```
Client::join('transactions_clients','clients.id','=','transactions_clients.client_id')
         ->select('transactions_clients.*','clients.name')->grouBy('transactions_clients.id')->get();
```

Controller search query:

```
$transaction_client = TransactionClient::transaction()->where('clients.name', 'LIKE', '%'.$input['search'].'%')->get();
```

I have others filter, I have load one.

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#available-methods

Comment: Can you show the entire query scope method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @algorhythm

```
TransactionClient::transaction()->filter(function ($transaction_client) use($input){
                                                        return stristr($transaction_client->name,$input['search']);
                                                    })->all();
```

Comment: Isn't is better to call `->get()` instead of `->all()` to be sure to get the filtered entries and not all? Try if it also works...

Comment: @algorhythm thanks, but i have changed my code, so i already fix that.